# Ignore part of the path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, wildcard

I would like to be able to ignore part of the paths in my application.
For example:
example.com/products/toys/big-toy, should be routed by ignoring the 'toys' part (just products/big-toy). I am aware of the wildcard symbol available in the routes, but it ignores everything after the products path. I am not sure how to do this and keep my nested resources working.

Routes:

```
resources :products do
  member do
    match :details
  end
  resources :photos
end
```

product.rb:

```
def to_param
  "#{category.slug}/#{slug}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to use a route constraint.

Try this:

```
resources :products, constraints: { id: /[^\/]+\/[^\/]+/ } do
    member do
      match :details, via: :get
    end
  resources :photos
end
```

This will capture the product `:id` as anything with a slash in the middle, so `/products/abc/xyz/details` will route to `products#details` with `params[:id]` equal to `abc/xyz`.

Then, you could add a before filter in your `ProductsController`, like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :parse_id

  // ...

  def parse_id
    slugs = params[:id].split("/")
    params[:category_id] = slugs[0]
    params[:id] = slugs[1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but what about all other routes like edit, index and the nested resource e.g. photos. Would `/products/toys/big-toy/photos` work?

Comment: Sorry @StefanAdamov, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to do what you want (I think).